# Searching Discord Users very slow - express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, discord.js

So, I am making an Express route for my Dashboard where users can use a search box and search for members (globally and not applied to the server). It will redirect to another page and show the results. I have the IDs stored in the DB.

For some reason, `search.js` is fetching everything from the DB at once and filtering. Therefore making it slow to load. Instead, I need to have the usernames, IDs etc. fetched from Discord.js with client.users.cache.get() and that loads faster, shown in `money.js`

Any help is appreciated.

here is `search.js`

```js
module.exports = async(req, res) => {

    let search = req.query.username;
    if (!search) return res.redirect("/stats");

    let out = [];
    db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`Levelings_`)).forEach(i => out.push(db.get(i.ID)));

    out = out.filter(u => !!u.id && (u.username.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase() ||
    u.username.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
    u.username.toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase()) ||
    search.toLowerCase().includes(u.username.toLowerCase()) ||
    search.toLowerCase().startsWith(u.username.toLowerCase())
    ))

    let struct = {
        bot: req.client,
        memberData: out,
        search: search
    };

    return res.render("search.ejs", struct)

}
```

`search.ejs`

```js
    <% if (memberData.length < 1) { %>
    <h4> No results were found!</h4>
    <% } %>
    <div class="row">
        <% memberData.forEach(mb => { %>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
            <div class="card bg-dark rounded text-white">
                <span class="bot-upvotes badge rounded badge-info"
                    style="font-size: 14px;width: 40%;margin-left: 140px;margin-top: -55px;">Upvotes:
                <div class="card-body mt-4">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><%= mb.username %></h5>
                    <a href="/stats/user/<%= mb.id %>" class="btn btn-success rounded">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }) %>
```

A working example for fetching users with discord.js. `money.js` leaderboard.

```js
    const coins = db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`coins`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data);

    coins.length = 50;
    let out = [];

    for (let i in coins) {
        if (coins[i].data === null) coins[i].data = 0;

        let ids = req.client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[1]) ? req.client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[1]).id : "";
        let vault = await db.fetch(`bankVault_${ids}`);
        
        out[out.length] = {
            username: req.client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[1]) ? req.client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[1]).username : "Unknown",
            discriminator: req.client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[1]) ? req.client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[1]).discriminator : "0000",
            id: ids,
            avatar: req.client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[1]) ? req.client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[1]).displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 64}) : "https://discordapp.com/assets/6debd47ed13483642cf09e832ed0bc1b.png?size=2048",
            coins: coins[i].data,
            vault: vault || `0`
        };
    };

    let struct = {
        bot: req.client,
        memberData: out
    };

    res.render("../views/leaderboard/money", struct);
```